# Go - How to test with http.NewRequest

Tags: go

I've got below code for testing http request:

```
func TestAuthenticate(t *testing.T) {
    api := &ApiResource{}
    ws := new(restful.WebService)
    ws.Consumes(restful.MIME_JSON, restful.MIME_XML)
    ws.Produces(restful.MIME_JSON, restful.MIME_JSON)
    ws.Route(ws.POST("/login").To(api.Authenticate))
    restful.Add(ws)

    bodyReader := strings.NewReader("<request><Username>42</Username><Password>adasddsa</Password><Channel>M</Channel></request>")

    httpRequest, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/login", bodyReader)
//  httpRequest.Header.Set("Content-Type", restful.MIME_JSON)
    httpRequest.Header.Set("Content-Type", restful.MIME_XML)
    httpWriter := httptest.NewRecorder()

    restful.DefaultContainer.ServeHTTP(httpWriter, httpRequest)
}
```

I tried to use json as a string with same `NewReader` and also tried to use struct with `json.Marshal`.

Neither of them works.

Is there a method where I can code `bodyReader` for a valid third parameter for `http.NewRequest`?

Similar request as input for `NewReader` in JSON is:

```
bodyReader := strings.NewReader("{'Username': '12124', 'Password': 'testinasg', 'Channel': 'M'}")
```

Struct fields are is:
`Username, Password, Channel`

Comment: strings.NewReader() is a valid way to create a request body reader. What exactly fails? Is it a compilation error, or a runtime other error. If it's a runtime error, where is it coming from? There are no error tests in the posted code.

Comment: It's not decoding properly with JSON and struct

Comment: @SimonFox JSON is the string on my question. It doesn't decode properly because I use `ReadEntity` on a `hello` struct that has `Useranem`, `Password` and `Channel` After `request.ReadEntity`, when I do `fmt.Println(hello.Username)` I get nothing but gets a panic error. This only happens with JSON not XML

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JSON is invalid. JSON uses `"` for quoting strings, not `'`.

Use this line of code to create the request body:

```
bodyReader := strings.NewReader(`{"Username": "12124", "Password": "testinasg", "Channel": "M"}`)
```

I used a [raw string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) to avoid quoting the `"` in the JSON text.